# Возврат из slice() пустого массива

Tags: javascript

Доброе время суток,столкнулся казалось бы с очень простой ситуацией: Получить из массива под массив. Код таков:

```
var r = [ { count: 4 },
      { count: 4 },
      { count: 3  },
      { count: 3 },
      { count: 1 },
      { count: 1 },
      { count: 0  },
      { count: 0 } ];

var seredina = r.length / 2;
// var array1 = r.slice(seredina,-(seredina /2)); // а так все нормально
var array1 = r.slice(seredina,2); // тут пустой массив
var array2 = r.slice(0,seredina);// массив первой половины изначального

 console.log(array1)
 console.log(array2);
```

В чем подвох? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте так получать вторую половину: ```var array1 = r.slice(seredina);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Syntax

Вторым аргументом метод `slice` принимает индекс, по которому надо заканчивать извлечение.

```
var array1 = r.slice(seredina,-(seredina /2));
```

В этом случае начальный индекс будет 4, конечным будет -2, то есть будет извлечен массив с 4-го элемента по второй элемент с конца.

```
var array1 = r.slice(seredina,2);
```

Этот пример вернет пустой массив, потому что начальный индекс меньше конечного, и конечный индекс неотрицательный